# ExtJS 6.2 - issue with initConfig

Tags: extjs6

ExtJS version 6.2

I'm not allowed to call initConfig() from my extended textfield, in a contructor. The error it thrown is that, 
`initConfig should not be called by subclasses, it will be called by Ext.Component(…)`.

For some reason I can't use callParent() there.
It was available in ExtJS 5.0. Any alternatives for this?

Comment: Why are you calling `initConfig`?

Comment: intiConfig will initialize object with the config passed and create getters and setters.

Comment: Right, but the error is telling you the superclass will call it. So why do you need to call it in your subclass?

Comment: Also, `initConfig` doesn't create the getters and setters, that happens at class definition time.

Comment: You can check this fiddle - (This works for 5.0 and doesn't work for 6.2). And this is just a flow I wanted (if it doesn't make any sense)  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1scp

Comment: Ok, but why do you need to do that? It seems largely pointless. There's no way to work around it, which is why I'm questioning the need to do so.

Comment: It's very much helpful in my app, because I need to apply common configurations(values are different) to different widgets. So I have a mixin and all my widgets implements that. There I have a common function which will be called before the creation of each widget. And there I set those configs, and save it in the widget, therefore it is available in the specific widget.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138516/discussion-between-codzilla-and-evan-trimboli).

Answer (score 0):

Use **Ext.apply(this, cfg)** instead of **initConfig()**. It will solve your issue.

Sample old code:

```
 constructor: function(cfg){
         this.initConfig(cfg);
    },
```

Sample correct code:

```
constructor: function(cfg){
    //this.initConfig(cfg);
    Ext.apply(this, cfg);

},
```